# SQL COUNT() Function

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I am trying to run a query on a table, for the sake of this question let's call it ABC. I am looking to count how many bank accounts correspond to a particular Company and VendorName. However this returns answers where the BankAcctNumber is the same, ie I have just a duplicate entry. I am looking to only return these entries where the BankAcctNumber for the two or more Company and VendorName entries are different. This code I have entered below runs and returns all Companys and VendorNames with a count on the BankAcctNumber > 1, but it hasn't identified only the ones where BankAcctNumber are different.

```
SELECT Company, VendorName, COUNT(BankAcctNumber)
FROM ABC
GROUP BY Company, VendorName
HAVING (COUNT(BankAcctNumber) > 1 )
```

Sorry if what I have said isn't clear, I am more than willing to clear up any fuzziness and lack of detail in my explanation.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT Company, VendorName, COUNT(DISTINCT BankAcctNumber)
FROM ABC
GROUP BY Company, VendorName;
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I should probably get to bed hey haha. Cheers for the help.
Will accept once it says I can.